# Effective way to determine time between posts?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I got an scenario and I was hoping if there's an much more efficient way to optimize the code for it, here we go.

Assume there's a table named `ticket_thread` with the following fields

- threadID
- ticketID
- threadType - could be c2s, s2s, s2c
- postTime - datetime
- message

and all data is sorted by ticketID, followed by postTime

My job is to determine the time needed for each c2s to s2c, aka response time.

My current approach is dump the filtered table into two lists - c2s, and s2c

```
while (!isempty($c2s) || !isempty($s2c)) {

  // popping first record from c2s
  $c2sRecord = array_shift($c2s);

  if (!$c2sRecord['ticketID'] == $s2c[0]['ticketID']) {

    // cannot find a response to the ticket
    echo $c2sRecord['ticketID'] . "<br>";

  } else {

    echo $c2sRecord['ticketID'];

    // popping first response from s2c
    $s2cRecord = array_shift($s2c);

    // print out the response time
    echo " " . date_diff($s2cRecord['postTime'], $c2sRecord['postTime']);

    $filter = true;
    while ($filter) {

      // checking the next record in c2s, if it is a different ticket 
      // OR the new post is placed AFTER service has responded.
      if (($c2s[0]['ticketID'] <> $s2cRecord['ticketID']) 
          or ($c2s[0]['postTime'] > $s2cRecord['postTime'])) {

        // stops the filter
        $filter = false;

      } else {

        // pop out unneeded records (supplementary questions) 
        $c2sRecord = array_shift($c2s);

      }
    }
  }
```

My problem is, this takes way too long, is there a quicker way I can manipulate with SQL to generate what I needed into something like this?

`table generated from SQL`

```
ticket_id | c2sTime  | s2cTime  | timeTaken | rank
  0012    | 12:20:20 | 12:30:20 | 00:10:00  |   1
  0012    | 12:40:00 | 12:55:30 | 00:15:30  |   2
  0012    | 13:10:20 |   null   |   null    |   3
  0013    | 12:20:20 |   null   |   null    |   1
```

**Edit: Sample table as requested**

```
threadID | ticketID | threadType | postTime | message
  3012   |   0012   |    c2s     | 12:20:20 | customer A's 1st post
  3014   |   0012   |    c2s     | 12:20:30 | Added info to A's 1st post, should not be included
  3015   |   0012   |    s2c     | 12:30:20 | Support responding to A's 1st post
  3016   |   0012   |    s2s     | 12:30:30 | internal chat, should not be included
  3017   |   0012   |    s2s     | 12:30:40 | internal chat, should not be included
  3018   |   0012   |    c2s     | 12:40:00 | A's 2nd post
  3019   |   0012   |    s2c     | 12:55:30 | Support responding to A's 2nd post
  3020   |   0012   |    s2c     | 13:00:00 | Added info to Support's 2nd response, should not be included
  3021   |   0012   |    c2s     | 13:10:00 | A's 3nd post
  3013   |   0013   |    c2s     | 12:20:20 | customer B's 1st post
```

Comment: Edit the question and add sample data from the table to get the desired output.

Comment: What is `rank` in your output? Is it just some numbering, which is based on the ordering? (aka. [`row_number()`/`rank()`/`dense_rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) kind-of-thing?)

Comment: @pozs yes, it's used so I can easily tell how many replies back and forth between the customer and the support members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task could be a lot simpler, if all [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) could support the `FILTER()` clause (like the aggregate-based variants do). I.e. all you **would** need is:

```sql
-- won't work, unfortunately
first_value(post_time) filter (where thread_type = 's2c')
                         over (partition by ticket_id
                               order by post_time
                               rows between current row and unbounded following)
```

Until then, you could use a self-join:

```
select  t.*, row_number() over (partition by t.ticket_id order by t.c2s_time) rank
from    (select    distinct on (coalesce(s2c.thread_id, c2s.thread_id))
                   c2s.ticket_id,
                   c2s.post_time c2s_time,
                   c2s.message c2s_message,
                   s2c.post_time s2c_time,
                   s2c.message s2c_message,
                   s2c.post_time - c2s.post_time time_taken
         from      ticket_thread c2s
         left join ticket_thread s2c on  c2s.ticket_id = s2c.ticket_id
                                     and s2c.thread_type = 's2c'
                                     and c2s.post_time < s2c.post_time
                                     and not exists(select 1
                                                    from   ticket_thread
                                                    where  post_time > c2s.post_time
                                                    and    post_time < s2c.post_time
                                                    and    ticket_id = c2s.ticket_id
                                                    and    thread_type = 's2c')
         where     c2s.thread_type = 'c2s'
         order by  coalesce(s2c.thread_id, c2s.thread_id), c2s.post_time) t
order by t.ticket_id, t.c2s_time;
```

Or, you could play around with `array_agg()` as a window function:

```
select  t.*, row_number() over (partition by t.ticket_id order by t.c2s_time) rank
from    (select    distinct on (coalesce((m).thread_id, (t).thread_id))
                   (t).ticket_id,
                   (t).post_time c2s_time,
                   (t).message c2s_message,
                   (m).post_time s2c_time,
                   (m).message s2c_message,
                   (m).post_time - (t).post_time time_taken
         from      (select t, array_agg(t) filter (where thread_type = 's2c')
                                             over (partition by ticket_id
                                                   order by     post_time
                                                   rows between current row and unbounded following) a
                    from   ticket_thread t) t
         left join lateral  (select   m
                             from     unnest(a) m
                             order by (m).post_time
                             limit    1) m on true
         where     (t).thread_type = 'c2s'
         order by  coalesce((m).thread_id, (t).thread_id), (t).post_time) t
order by t.ticket_id, t.c2s_time;
```

From my internal testing, it seems that the self-join variant is a little faster & it also has the possibility to use index(es) on `(ticket_id, post_time)`. (But you should test both, if performance really matters to you).

Or, you could also add the missing functionality (i.e. create a `first_agg` aggregate & use it as a window function):

```
create or replace function first_agg_val(anyelement, anyelement)
  returns anyelement
  language sql
  immutable
  strict
  as 'select $1';

create aggregate first_agg(
  sfunc    = first_agg_val,
  basetype = anyelement,
  stype    = anyelement
);

select  t.*, row_number() over (partition by t.ticket_id order by t.c2s_time) rank
from    (select    distinct on (coalesce((s2c).thread_id, (c2s).thread_id))
                   (c2s).ticket_id,
                   (c2s).post_time c2s_time,
                   (c2s).message c2s_message,
                   (s2c).post_time s2c_time,
                   (s2c).message s2c_message,
                   (s2c).post_time - (c2s).post_time time_taken
         from      (select t c2s, first_agg(t) filter (where thread_type = 's2c')
                                                 over (partition by ticket_id
                                                       order by     post_time
                                                       rows between current row and unbounded following) s2c
                    from   ticket_thread t) t
         where     (c2s).thread_type = 'c2s'
         order by  coalesce((s2c).thread_id, (c2s).thread_id), (c2s).post_time) t
order by t.ticket_id, t.c2s_time;
```

If you don't need `rank`, you can get rid of the outer queries (they are exists, purely for `rank`). (That is usually easy to calculate on the client side, instead.)

http://rextester.com/BUY9309

PS: my queries' `time_taken` column is an [`interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html). If you don't like/can't parse that column, you could use the following formula instead, to get the time difference **in seconds**:

```
extract(epoch from <interval expresssion>)
```

Comment: hi @pozs, thanks for your prompt reply. Your script almost worked, but in the case of customer sends in two or more post BEFORE the staff replied (eg: http://rextester.com/BLIJ77843) both of your script fails. Well, the second way almost worked, if the additional post message wasn't showing, then that's exactly what I wanted. EDIT: I added in the message just to use it as a comment.

Comment: @Willy_Sunny I see; you'll need slightly more advanced queries then. I updated my post, please check it out.

Comment: Hm. For some reason, when I tried to use the script on my work machine, it kept telling me that there's a synax error at or near the filter statement, not sure if it's because I'm working on 9.3 while the website is using 9.6 =\

Comment: @Willy_Sunny yes, the `filter` clause is a 9.4+ feature. For 9.3, you could use the first variant (emulating the `filter` would require even more complex query, which is not worth it, if we have an alternative approach).

Comment: Thanks your script worked great, but I've noticed a bug (and I've fixed it) is that your not exist filter should include a "ticket_id = c2s.ticket_id" in the filter, or in the case of support answering second customer first before answering the first customer, would cause an error (Bugged Version: http://rextester.com/BTB49241) (Fiixed version: http://rextester.com/BUY9309)

Comment: @Willy_Sunny yeah, you're right. The other variants handle that case already, but the JOIN variant needs the extra `ticket_id = c2s.ticket_id` predicate. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using mainly window functions:

```
select ticketid, c2stime, s2ctime, s2ctime- c2stime as timetaken, rank() over w
from (
    select ticketid, threadtype, posttime as c2stime, lead(posttime) over w as s2ctime
    from (
        select *, lag(threadtype) over w
        from ticket_thread
        where threadtype <> 's2s'
        window w as (partition by ticketid order by threadid)
        ) s
    where threadtype <> coalesce(lag, '')
    window w as (partition by ticketid order by threadid)
    ) s
where threadtype = 'c2s'
window w as (partition by ticketid order by c2stime)
order by ticketid, c2stime;

 ticketid | c2stime  | s2ctime  | timetaken | rank 
----------+----------+----------+-----------+------
       12 | 12:20:20 | 12:30:20 | 00:10:00  |    1
       12 | 12:40:00 | 12:55:30 | 00:15:30  |    2
       12 | 13:10:00 |          |           |    3
       13 | 12:20:20 |          |           |    1
(4 rows)
```